# Clever if in R like in c++

Tags: r, if-statement

Is there is a way in R language to write a fast IF like in C++:

```
if (a==b)
    return 1
else
    return 0
// Fast way
(a==b ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: just fyi, what you call clever if is actually known as ternary operator in c++. (because it has 3 operands)

Comment: another one `+(a == b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually R's `ifelse()` function already sort of encapsulates the same behavior as a C-style ternary expression:

```r
ifelse(a == b, 1, 0)
```

Note that `ifelse` is already *vectorized*, meaning that the inputs `a` and `b` can be vectors, and it will still work.

Comment: But if I try to output c(0,1,0) or something like that, I am getting just the first number
For example: ifelse(a == b, c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0))

Comment: That's not how `ifelse` works.  Each pair of values at every index of `a` and `b` get compared, and a single _scalar_ value is the output, not a vector output.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- if(a==b) 1 else 0
```

you can write that way

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the logical values returned from `==` to integer in R. So this should work.

```
as.integer(a == b)
```

For example,

```
a <- c(2, 4, 5, 6)
b <- c(3, 4, 7, 6)
as.integer(a==b)
#[1] 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(a == b ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)
```